# Python inheritance problems

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    class partner(object):
       _table = 'partner'

       def sendsms(self):
          print "I am partners"

       def sendemail(self):
          print "send email"


    class student(partner):

      _inherit = 'partner'    
      _table = 'student'

      def sendsms(self):
        print "I am student"
        print "@@", self._inherit
        print "###", self._table
        super(student,self).sendsms()

    class student(student):

      _inherit = 'student'

      def fees(self):
        print "1000 INR"

   t = student()
   t.sendsms()
```

this will go in recursion, what does problem or inheritance issues ?

Comment: What do you intend to do with `class student(student):`

Comment: Why you are inheriting student from student ?

Comment: You can't have "recursion" of class definitions.

Comment: Hello, first I inherit partner in student class, then I have some other class abc , now again student class where class abc use it.

Comment: "now again student class": there seems to be missing a verb in this part of the sentence. it might help to understand what you want to do.

Comment: Don't delete the text from your questions. You will get banned or suspended for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

`class student(student):` is a line of code that simply doesn't make sense. If you do something like

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class partner(object):
    _table = 'partner'

    def sendsms(self):
        print "I am partners"

    def sendemail(self):
        print "send email"


class student(partner):

    _inherit = 'partner'    
    _table = 'student'

    def sendsms(self):
        print "I am student"
        print "@@", self._inherit
        print "###", self._table
        super(student,self).sendsms()

class student2(student):

    _inherit = 'student'

    def fees(self):
        print "1000 INR"

t = student2()
t.sendsms()
```

instead, it works, but this is probably not what you want to do. Without further explanation we can't really help you.

BTW, above code gives:

```
I am student
@@ partner
### student
I am partners
```

Comment: Why class student(student): not perform well and not able to execute sendsms method. !

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this. `class student(student):` simply is not possible. Why do you call your third class also student? Why don't you give it another name? Or the other way around: if you want to extend student by another method `fees`: just add it to the previous class.

Comment: Actually `class student(student)` makes perfect sense. It means "create a new class that inherits from the class currently bound to the name `student`, and then bind the name `student` to this new class". It's probably not a good idea, but it's valid Python that has a well-defined meaning.

Comment: You're right, I wasn't very clear. I wanted to say that I wouldn't do it and wouldn't recommend to do it. It's hacky, and should only be used if there is no other solution, as it it confusing and makes it unnecessarily hard to understand and maintain the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
super(student,self).sendsms()
```

takes the global name `student` (which is, at the time of calling, the 2nd one), takes its parent (which is the 1st one) and calls its `.sendsms()`. Voilà your recursion.

The solution would be to rename your 2nd class so that the first name is not shadowed.